# MS Access Security warning pops up when opening an MS Access accde file located in a Trusted Location

Tags: ms-access, security, registry

I can't get rid of the MS Access Security warning when opening an MS Access *accde* UI file located in a Trusted Location. Despite reviewing lots of information on the subject, I've obviously missed something, but can't see what that is.

## The scenario

The UI is an Access.accde file which is located in a user's *C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\UIfolder* folder.

Within Trusted Locations of AccessUI.accde is the User Location path `C:\%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\UIfolder\`

I crafted a vbs that creates a Trusted Location in the registry named *UI_Location* with a path of `C:\%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\UIfolder\`

**I expected** AccessUI.accde to be trusted.

**What actually happened**
Whenever I open AccessUI.accde the Microsoft Access Security Notice, warning of a potential security concern, pops up with options to Open or Cancel.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to get rid of the Security warning?
Tks

---

### Edit: Further investigation following xShen reply.

With my script changed to set a Registry path for a specific user `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\UIfolder\`
AccessUI.accdb as well as AccessUI.accde opens with NO security warnings.

With my script modified to reset the Registry path for a variable user `C:\%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\UIfolder\`
AccessUI.accdb opened with NO security warnings.
Then the AccessUI.accde also opened with NO security warnings, even though nothing had changed in the UI.

Further investigation needed!

Comment: perhaps this will help:  https://www.devhut.net/microsoft-office-trusted-documents-and-trusted-locations/

Comment: xShen, tks for that. My vbs is a heavily modified version of devhut's script. Functionally similar but using an expanded string to support the variable string %UserProfile%. Nevertheless, I reviewed my solution and no changes are required but will edit my question to reflect  an unexpected development.

Comment: And the 'unexpected development' is the issue no longer occurs?

Comment: It is not quite clear from your question if you realize this: Trusted Locations have *nothing* to do with any single .accde or .accdb - they are stored in the registry, and apply to *all* databases located in this path. Open Access without any db and open Trust Center to see them.